# How does Rovagug’s Fury work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, trip

The spell says:

> You create a minor earthquake that can trip creatures. Make a single trip attack and use the result against every creature in the area. Those that fail are tripped and fall prone. You do not provoke an attack of opportunity for this trip attack (though you do provoke one for casting the spell), nor can you knock yourself prone with a bad roll."

Being a spell caster and new to pathfinder, do I just roll a D20 and add my CMB (Base attack bonus + Strength modifier + special size modifier) and then compare to their CMD's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You just roll a 1d20, add your CMB, and compare to their CMD.

Yes, you seem to have grasped exactly how [Rovagug's Fury](http://archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Rovagug%27s%20Fury) works.

It causes the [Trip Maneuver](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip), but with the exceptions listed on the spell description.

There are not many spells that use your CMB like that, without considering your caster level or primary ability modifier, so this may seem like a strange spell, but that's how it works.